# How to parse a string of commands that appear multiple times into an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a template engine, I have the following input:

```
<!-- #page main -->
<!-- #content head -->
<head></head>
<!-- #content body -->
Some text inside body content
<body></body>
<!-- #content footer -->
<footer></footer>
```

I want the following output:

```
{ head: `<head></head>`,
    body: `Some text inside body content<body></body>`,
    footer: `<footer></footer>` }
```

Basically I want to consume all the  commands and push them into an
array. How can I do that?

I've tried some complex string matching but It went amok.

```
const regPageContent = /<!-- #content \b(\w+)\b -->\n([\s\S]*)/;
const regPageContentRest = /([\s\S]*)<!-- #content \b\w+\b -->/;


function page(page, layout, replace) {

  if (!layout) {
    return [
      fappend(page)
    ];
  }
  let res = [];
  let rest = page;
  let match,
      secondmatch;

  if (replace) {
    secondmatch = rest.match(regPageContentRest);

    if (secondmatch) {
      res.push(
        freplace(replace, secondmatch[1])
      );
      rest.substring(secondmatch[1].length);
    } else {
      res.push(
        freplace(replace, rest)
      );
    }

  while (rest.length > 0) {

    match = rest.match(regPageContent);

    if (match) {
      secondmatch = match[2].match(regPageContentRest);

      console.log(rest);
      console.log('rest');
      console.log(match[2]);

      if (secondmatch) {
        res.push(
          freplace(match[1], secondmatch[1])
        );
        rest.substring(secondmatch[1].length);
      } else {
        res.push(
          freplace(match[1], match[2])
        );
        break;
      }
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  res.push(flayout(layout));

  return res;
}
```

To abstract the problem, instead of html this could be like:

```
command 1
  info 1
command 2
  info 2
  more info 2
command 3
info 3
```

and the output:

```
{ 1: 'info 1', 2: 'info 2\n more info 2', 3: 'info 3' }
```

Comment: Could you use another library that knows how to read html/xml?  Or do you have to do this from scratch?

Comment: take a look at getElementsByTagName("*");

Comment: I want to code my own, also the command uses html syntax, it could be anything.

Comment: Looks like a job for a DomParser rather than regex. Comments in dom have a nodeType and textContent so can be read easily for example

Comment: Can I make a small version of a DomParser to solve this specific issue, I don't want the full bloated DomParser code.

Comment: Are you running this in node or browser?

Comment: it's a static site generator, so it's nodejs

Comment: Curious how you arrive at that input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221427/discussion-between-eguneys-and-charlietfl).

Comment: So you want to write an xml parser?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you gotta loop through the string looking for a certain keyword, in this case, `command`, then continue looping through the string until you find a character immediately following that keyword, and keep looking until you reach an invalid character (in this case a non integer), then save the index of the main string you are at now, then continue looping and look for the same keyword again, if found, save index, then make a new object containing the content from first index to last index just found, and push it to some array or something, then continue along the main string. If no additional keyword is found, then consider the final index as if it was the index of the next keyword etc.

This entire middle process should be a function of it's own, with a parameter containing the main original string, the start index, the keyword, and some kind of array to push the values into it (or just have it return this value) then in the main code scope start the calling the function when you find the keyword etc. Tree function should somehow (also) return the index that the end keyword was found at, and this can be used to recursively call it until the index is -1, in which case the end of the main string can be used instead

That's at least the theory i had when brainstorming this, but the implementation can be even simpler

Anyways basically

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <title>Untitled</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <textarea  id="ok"></textarea>
 <div  id="ko"></div>
 <div id="u"></div>
<script>
ok.onkeyup= ok.onchange=ok.onfocus=
function () {
    ko. innerText=JSON
    .stringify(parseIt(ok.value))
}

    function parseIt(str) {
function
getContentBetweenKeywords(keyword, wordList) {
    var contents = []
    getIt()

    function getIt() {
        var i, k
        for (i = 0; i < wordList.length-1; i++) {
            if (wordList[i].word == keyword) {
            
                if (isAllDigits(wordList[i + 1].word)) {
                    var foundIndex = -1

                    for (k = i + 1; k < wordList.length; k++) {
                        if (wordList[k].word == keyword) {
                            foundIndex = k
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    var endInd = foundIndex > -1 ? wordList[foundIndex].index : str.length
                    contents[
                        wordList[i+1]. word
                    ]=(str.substring(wordList[i + 1].index + wordList[i + 1].word.length, endInd))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return contents
}

function getKeywords(str, start, end) {
    var i, chars = "QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNMqwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm1234567890$",
        startWord = -1,
        words = []
    for (i =  0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (chars.includes(str[i])) {
            if (startWord == -1) {
                startWord = i;
            }
        } else if (startWord != -1) {
            words.push({
                word: str.substring(startWord, i),
                index: startWord
            })

            startWord = -1
        }
    }
    return words
}

function isAllDigits(str) {
    str = (str + "").trim()
    var digits = "1234567890",
        i
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (!digits.includes(str[i])) return false
    }
    return true
}
//alert(isAllDigits("478h"))
    u.innerText=JSON.stringify(getKeywords(str))
return getContentBetweenKeywords
(
    "command", 
    getKeywords(str)
)

}
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can achieve the same with the following script:

```js
const text=`command 1
  info 1
command 2
  info 2
  more info 2
command 3
info 3`, text2=
`<!-- #page main -->
<!-- #content head -->
<head></head>
<!-- #content body -->
<body>
Some text inside body content
</body>
<!-- #content footer -->
<footer></footer>`;

console.log(xtract(text,"command"));
console.log(xtract(text2,"#content",2));

function xtract(text,keyword,idx=1){
 let res=text.split("\n").reduce((acc,line)=>{
   let kw=line.trim().split(" "); // try for keyword:
   if (line.match(keyword)) acc.curr=(acc[kw[idx]]=acc[kw[idx]]||[]);
   else if (acc.curr)   acc.curr.push(line.trim());
   return acc;
 }, {}); 
 delete res.curr;
 // in case you don't want arrays, but simple text strings as properties:
 Object.keys(res).forEach(k=>res[k]=res[k].join("\n"))
 return res; 
}
```

The function `xtract()` requires two compulsary and one optional arguments: the `text`, a `keyword` string serving as a marker for a "commandlet" and `idx` for the name to be used for the following section. The `idx`-th word of the commandlet line will be picked to become the section name (if no value is given a default of `idx=1` is assumed).

IMHO a DOMparser is *not the right tool* here, as you don't really want to parse any HTML or XML text. Instead you want to react on certain "commandlets" strewn into the text that define into which object properties the following text fragments are to be imported. And `xtract()` does exactly that.